# Google Chrome Launch With Custom Profile/User

Tags: linux, shell, google-chrome, command-line

I am using Google Chrome 34.0.x on Linux Mint 14.

I have a script that starts the browser at some point to go to a specific Webpage. I want to keep that browsing history separate from the one I actively use. So, I created multiple users under Settings->Users .

But I can't seem to find the command line switch to specify an user name.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a separate user, use an entirely separate data directory: `--user-data-dir=some/new/dirpath`, it'll be created if it doesn't exist yet.  Everything about it will be entirely separate from your default set of profiles.